# Sublevel sets of concave function

Tags: convex-analysis

On Page 75 of Boyd's Convex Optimization:

> A function can have all its sublevel sets convex but not be a convex
>   function. For example,$ f(x)=-e^x$ is not convex on $R$ but all its
>   sublevel sets are convex.

I don not quite understand that. How to tell the sublevel of $ f(x)=-e^x$ are convex? I think they are all concave as the $f(x)$ itself.

Comment: The set described by the inequality $-e^x \leq a$, when $a<0$, is exactly equivalent to the set described by $x \geq \log-a$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Yeah, but isn't it concave?

Comment: You are confusing convex/concave functions and convex sets. There is no such thing as a concave set in the context of convex optimization.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Oh, You are right!